# C++: How can I do zoom like Google Maps?

Tags: c++, mouse, mousewheel, zooming

I'm programming in the Windows API using C++. For this program, I'm using the Traslating and Scaling 3D MATRIX, and also I'm using the WM_MOUSEWHEEL event. This is a part of the code:

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    rotw = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam);
    if (rotw > 0)
        zoom += 0.05f;
    else
        zoom -= 0.05f;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, false);
    break;
```

For the implementation, I'm using this:

```
Translation(xPos,yPos)*Scaling(zoom, zoom)
```

But the problem is that the zoom isn't correct, because it 'jumps' from one point to other, making confusing and difficult to do zoom in a certain point.
I was reading something about calculate the new X and Y point with the new X and Y point and use a zoom factor (I guess my zoom factor is the variable 'zoom').

[This is the main window, with a random picture. I put the pointer in the mustache and apply zoom with the mouse wheel...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h8IG.png)

[But after I did the zoom, this happends. The zoom wasn't made in the place that I wanted!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmSD.png)

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!